# How to get the icon for a file extension or filetype without creating a temp file?

Tags: java, file, swing, icons, desktop

I list some filenames with their icons (like the ones in the Windows Explorer) in a `JTable`. I know the two ways to get the icon if I have a `File` object from the local file system:

```
javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( file )
```

for a 16x16 icon or for a bigger one:

```
sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.getShellFolder( file ).getIcon( true ) )
```

Since my files are stored in a database, I don't have the `File` object. My workaround is to create a temp file with the specific filename extension, use one of the two methods above and cache the icon to display it in a CellRenderer.

I searched for a solution without temporary files and found two I don't like either:

- `org.eclipse.swt.program.Program.findProgram(String extension).getImageData()`, but I don't want to use SWT
- `org.jdesktop.jdic.icons.IconService` from the Incubator of the [JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic) project. The last changes on the `IconService` are 6 years ago, on JDIC 2 years ago and I can't find a downloadable jar.

Is there another solution?

Comment: I changed Swing tag to the SWT tag

Comment: Why?  The poster explicitly said that they didn't want to use SWT.

Comment: From browing the source FileSystemView uses ShellFolder internally. ShellFolder itself doesnt implement getIcon. But Win32ShellFolder2 does(source link available) http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.html

Comment: I changed the tag back to SWING. Quoting myself: "...but I don't want to use SWT"

Comment: What is a `ShellFolder`?  I can't see it in the J2SE 7 class-list.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's a sun.awt class - nothing to call in your security restricted environments, (grin)

Comment: @kleopatra  I have *some* projects that are not deployed as an applet **or** via JWS (i.e. no security manager)!  But those are few and far between.  ;)

Comment: @kleopatra ..but as to the sun.* hierarchy of classes.  (shudder) There are very good reasons not to use them even in an app. with no security manager.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't disagree :-)

Comment: Shell icon handlers are allowed to look at the file so they can e.g. generate a thumbnail of the image to use as the icon. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a generic way to do this for no file, e.g. as they use in the 'open with' menu, but it might come down to parsing the registry entries yourself and ignoring the registered COM handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looks](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20get%20icon%20for%20file%20type&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&safe=active) like you already discovered the way to do it, unless you want to dive into native libraries etc.

[FileSystemView](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.java.html) uses [Win32ShellFolder](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.java.html) internally so they are basically the same.

I also dug up the Source for [org.eclipse.swt.program.Program](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/swt/program/Program.java.html) and with it [org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OS.java.html). The OS class then uses a native call for the Icon. At this point unless you really really cannot create a Temp File i would not go down that path.

For JDIC i only found http://kickjava.com/src/org/jdesktop/jdic/tray/internal/impl/WinTrayIconService.java.htm with a little bit of digging(may not be related but does icony things :D). Also calls native.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the temporary file to use the first option? A File does not have to denote a file that actually exists...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the two first options only work after the `file = new File("easyasabc.pdf")` File object was created _on disk_ with `file.createNewFile()`.