# Get Image/Icon associated with file extension in Java

Tags: java, file-extension

How can I get the icon/image associated with an file extension in Java?

Comment: Could you clarify your question better? You want to get an image from your file system?

Comment: If you look in the explorer, you see a little icon next to each file. This little one is the one I meant

Comment: This should help you out: `javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( file )`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521294/how-to-get-the-icon-for-a-file-extension-or-filetype-without-creating-a-temp-fil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`Icon ico = javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon( file )`

To show it on a label, just add it to a JLabel:
`myJpanel.add(new JLabel(ico));`