# Getting System Icon Without Path

Tags: java, swing

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File("C:/folder/text.txt"));
```

but I cant get a Icon without Path. How to can I do this?

Comment: What is your goal? The function only makes sense when passing a file because it returns the icon that would be displayed for that file. Calling it without a file makes no sense because what icon should be displayed for no file?

Comment: I am working for a Download Manager. I want display file's System Icon before downloading progress

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8521294/2442804 => *"I don't have the File object. My workaround is to create a temp file with the specific filename extension, use one of the two methods above and cache the icon to display it"*.

Comment: @luk2302 [quoting] *"My workaround is to create a temp file.."* Huh .. I'd thought it was only necessary to instantiate a file (rather than actually create a file), but tested that and .. `null` icon. **After** creating the file, this is what it might [look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5Ke8.png) using the native PLAF on Windows.